# Angular very weird bug on a custom element

Tags: angular, select

I have made a custom select element and I have a weird bug occurring.

Here I have reproduced the bug: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ff7i5j

The new-address component is the component which produces this bug. I can select an item from the select component just once, after that it seems like the function `OptionSelectedEvent` from `select.ts` is no more called.

I really don't know why first example works very well and in the new-address component it doesn't work.

I hope somebody can help me with this weird problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is going on here is that using getters in Angular templates can lead to many problems we didn't anticipate.

I'm talking about these getters in your code:

```
public get Judete(): any[] {
  return [{auto: "AB", nume: "Alba"}, {auto: "AR", nume: "Arad"}...];
}
```

Angular checks template bindings and executes all getters on every change detection cycle. That template gets new instance of `Judete` array with new instances of every item on every check.

Now let's see where you use that array.

```
*ngFor="let item of Judete"
```

Angular built-in `ngForOf` directive uses special algorithm to find the changes in your array with the help of `IterableDiffers`. This differ discovers that your array is completely a new array on every change detection cycle which results in rerender items. This means that new SelectOptionComponent items are created on every change detection run and you lose subscriptions for your ContentChildren

[image]

So the solution should be simple: just define your arrays once instead of using getters:

```
Judete =  [{auto: "AB", nume: "Alba"}, {auto: "AR", nume: "Arad"}, ...];
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azkxxs?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**